# Why page output has crlf when page has asp:SqlDataSource tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to output success status without crlf.
I have a simple page like this:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" validateRequest="false" %>
<!--#include file=config.aspx"-->
<asp:SqlDataSource
    id="database"
    runat="server"
    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    ConnectionString="Data Source=jjj10;Initial Catalog=highscores2;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=dbuser;Password=xxxx"
    SelectCommand="">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<script runat="server">
void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e ){
        Response.Write("success=true");     }
</script>
```

for some reason system adds crlf to end when sqldatasource tag is present.
If I remove this tag, there is no crlf.

Is it possible to send this output without CRLF at end?
The receiver module does not accept the crlf.

I need to use database.  Or is it possible to move tag to include file?

Comment: `Response.Write()` doens't add `\r\n`. Do you call `Response.Clear()`? Does the page contain any markup or a newline?

Comment: Have a look at the HttpResponse class and the underlying objects. Look a ClearHeaders and other methods. You can also use Output and OutputStream properties to achieve what you want.

Comment: @CodeCaster In theory you are right. Are you positive though?

Comment: I used this tool to detect there was crlf; http://www.rexswain.com/cgi-bin/httpview.cgi

Comment: Hi there is no response.clear or anything. Is there perhaps some global IIS setting that adds crlf automatically?

Comment: I have now added a full example and reason for bug

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove CRLF after this line

```
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```